# Swift 3.1 - Unable to fetch facebook friends id

Tags: ios, facebook, graph, sdk, request

I'm trying to print a list of my facebook friends' id but the result is empty. Any ideas?

```
  FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me/friends", parameters:["fields": "id"]).start{(connection, result, err)in

        if err != nil{
            print("errorGraph")
            return
        }

        else{
            guard let data = result as? [String:Any] else { return }
            let fbid = data["id"]

            print("friendID:", fbid ?? "")



        }}
```

Comment: When I remove /friends I get the user's facebook id...

Comment: me/friends only return app friends.

Comment: @WizKid I know, and I have installed it on a friends phone. The result is not empty.

Comment: When I change it to "data" instead of "id" I get this: friendID: (
        {
        id = 10154761104899086;
        name = "Ola Kirkerud";
    }
) But I only want to output the id, not the whole json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var faceFriendIDs:Array<Any> = []


FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me/friends", parameters:["fields":"id"]).start{(connection, result, error)in

        let resultDict = result as! NSDictionary
        let data:NSArray = resultDict.object(forKey: "data") as! NSArray

        for i in 0..<(data.count){
            let valueDict:NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
            let id = valueDict.object(forKey: "id") as! String
            self.faceFriendIDs.append(id)
        }



        print(self.faceFriendIDs)

    }
```